# Boto3: File Upload to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

In Boto3, how can I check if file uploading is done successfully with no errors?

Upon failing to upload, what sort of response do I get?

In the case of `put_object`, the response looks as follows([ref.](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object)):

```
{
    'Expiration': 'string',
    'ETag': 'string',
    'ServerSideEncryption': 'AES256'|'aws:kms',
    'VersionId': 'string',
    'SSECustomerAlgorithm': 'string',
    'SSECustomerKeyMD5': 'string',
    'SSEKMSKeyId': 'string',
    'RequestCharged': 'requester'
}
```

Does any of these parameters tell you whether uploading was successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service will return an [error response code](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html), which botocore will convert to a `ClientError`. Wire errors will be passed along as well after some attempts to handle the error.

Comment: so if I do not get those error codes upon calling the service and do get the HTTPStatusCode 200, can I assume the my services calls such as uploading and downloading objects went successful?

Comment: Yes, you can make that assumption.